# Pepper Robot Connected But Show Offline On Connected Device

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-7, robot, pepper

I try to connect to the Pepper robot using my Windows 7 laptop. It is connected and I am able to view the Robot Viewer using Android Studio, but it shows "offline" when I want to deploy the Pepper robot.

I have tried:

1. uninstall Vysor
2. kill adb.exe on my task manager
3. Restart the robot and my PC

Any other solutions?

Screenshot showing the problem:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Are your SDK platform-tools up-to-date? Also, have you activated the debug option on the tablet? Are you asked for your password when you connect the robot?

Try to run `adb kill-server` by command line and then try again:

1- Disconnect the robot
2- Connect again (make sure you connect to the **robot** ip and not the tablet ip)
3- Try to select target